# Are JWS web services (using .jws files) still working on weblogic 12c?

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, weblogic12c

Are JWS web services (using .jws files) still working on weblogic 12c or do they need to be migrated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theses types of web services need to be migrated.

See the following documentation : 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13760/upgrade.htm#WSRPC226